# Aforge C# DSLR camera remote control

Tags: c#, image-processing, aforge

I just want to ask if its possible to use nikon DSLR camera to be remotely controlled and program it using Aforge library in VS Desktop App C# ? So what i wanted to do is make a program that will use a dslr cam as a web cam and take pictures with it. So far i have made it work using my webcam but not in my dslr camera. If you guys have any reference how to do it in C# that would be helpful thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If your camera has a feature to wirelessly tethered over LAN using IP then you can use the JPEGStream that Aforge.Net offers. It's basically the same as accessing an IP Cam (assuming that your camera supports it),

http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/features/jpeg_video_streams.html

For the controls I think there's no support for it in the framework that'll let you control your camera. Though you can recreate certain features such as zoom, brightness, contrast and etc in the client side using Aforge.